How to make this soft sphere with Unity?
What methods should be used to create such a sphere in UNITY? This collider seems to deform in real-time, squeezing and monitoring collision information when the sphere collides. I cannot achieve this effect with the OBI plugin.


We have some past Q&A discussing this exact case

"I cannot achieve this effect with the OBI plugin." -> Why? What did you try and what problems did you encounter?
